# Question on notations and the Joint of $\sigma$-algebras

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Suppose $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ a complete probability space.

Assume $X,Y$ and $Z$ be three r.v.s $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$-measurables.

1. In general : Does $\sigma(X,Y)=\sigma(X)\vee\sigma(Y)$ ? **Is it the definition of $\sigma(X,Y)$** ?
2. If no : Under which condition(s) ? independance ?
3. Does $\sigma(X,Y,Z)=\sigma(X,Y)\vee\sigma(Z)=\sigma(X)\vee\sigma(Y)\vee\sigma(Z)$ ?
4. and so on, if 3. is good, we make an induction ....

---

What I think for question 1. (probably wrong) :

On one hand, I assume the following definition (probably wrong) : $\sigma(X,Y)=\{X^{-1}(A)\cup Y^{-1}(A):  A\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)\}=\sigma(\{X^{-1}((a,b])\cup Y^{-1}((a,b]):  a,b\in\mathbb R\})$

On the other hand : $\sigma(X)\vee\sigma(Y)=\sigma(\sigma(X)\cup \sigma(Y))=\sigma (\{X^{-1}(A):  A\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)\}\cup \{Y^{-1}(A):  A\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)\})$, I denote $=\sigma (X\cup Y)$

We have $\sigma(X,Y)=\sigma(X)\vee\sigma(Y)$ **iif** the $\Pi$-systems : $\Pi_{\sigma (X\cup Y)}$ and $\Pi_{\sigma(X,Y)}$ are equals.

We also have $\sigma(X,Y)\subseteq\sigma(X)\vee\sigma(Y)$ (easy to check).

I am not sure for the opposite but w.l.o.g. :

Lets $A\cap B\in\sigma(X)$ (not necessarily $A\cap B\in\sigma(Y)$), so it exists $a,b\in \mathbb R$ s.t. $A\cap B\in\{X^{-1}((a,b])\}\subseteq \{X^{-1}((a,b])\cup Y^{-1}((a,b])\}$.
Since $A\cap B\in\sigma(X)$ then $A\cap B\in\sigma(X)\cup\sigma(Y)$.
And by the monotone class theorem we have proved the assertion in question 1.

---

If my lasts arguments are wrongs : Does the opposite inclusion could be checked only under specific conditions on the $\Pi$-systems ?

Comment: It's better not to have all these separate questions in one post. This is generally discouraged. I recommend that you put your questions 3 and 4 in a different post.

Comment: @MattS, I disagree; it's basically one question: is $\sigma(X_{1},\dots,X_{n}) = \bigvee_{i = 1}^{n} \sigma(X_{i})$?

Comment: Ah. The question's been edited. It certainly looks better now.

Comment: Yes, it has been edited and yes it can be summarized as : Do we have $\sigma(X_1,....,X_n)=\vee^n_{i=1}\sigma(X_i)$?

Comment: You should begin by carefully re-reading the definition of $\sigma(X,Y)$.  Until you get that correct, there's no way you can solve the problem.

Comment: @AndreasBlass - Because in $\sigma(X,Y)$, $X,Y$ as to be seen as a vector $(X,Y)$ on $(\mathbb R^2,\mathcal B (\mathbb R^2))$, and in $\sigma(X)\vee\sigma(Y)$ it is a 1-dimensional $\sigma$-union (on $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$) ?